# Bar labels in matplotlib/Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

In version 3.4, matplotlib added automatic Bar labels:
https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/whats_new.html#new-automatic-labeling-for-bar-charts

I'm trying to use this on a bar plot generated by Seaborn.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(
        nrows=2,
    )        

for i, col in enumerate(['col_1', 'col_2']):
        ax = axs[i]
        sns.barplot(
            x="class",
            y=col,
            hue="hue_col",
            data=data_df,
            edgecolor=".3",
            linewidth=0.5,
            ax=ax
        )


        ax.bar_label(ax.containers[i]) # Doesn't work
```

What do I need to do to make this work? [example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Blz3a.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Does it give an error, or wrong output, or what?

Comment: The issue is getting it to work with NaN values. There are different ways of getting NaN values into the bar container, the most obvious is to use the "order" parameter in sns.barplot, giving it a value like ['male', 'female', 'non-binary'] in the titanic example below. This will include non-binary in the plot (indicating 0), but bar_label will then return this error: `File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 2638, in bar_label ha=ha, va=va, **kwargs) UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ha' referenced before assignment`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can loop through the containers and call `ax.bar_label(...)` for each of them. Note that seaborn creates one set of bars for each hue value.

The following example uses the titanic dataset and sets `ci=None` to avoid the error bars overlapping with the text (if error bars are needed, one could set a lighter color, e.g. `errcolor='gold'`).

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 4))

for ax, col in zip(axs, ['age', 'fare']):
    sns.barplot(
        x='sex',
        y=col,
        hue="class",
        data=titanic,
        edgecolor=".3",
        linewidth=0.5,
        ci=None,
        ax=ax
    )
    ax.set_title('mean ' + col)
    ax.margins(y=0.1) # make room for the labels
    for bars in ax.containers:
        ax.bar_label(bars, fmt='%.1f')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: seaborn barplot with ax.bar_label]

Comment: Follow-up question: Can I get it to work with NaN values? 
There are different ways of getting NaN values into the bar container, the most obvious is to use the "order" parameter in sns.barplot, giving it a value like ['male', 'female', 'non-binary'] in the titanic example. This will include non-binary in the plot (indicating 0), but bar_label will then return this error:
File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/model-runner-test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 2638, in bar_label
    ha=ha, va=va, **kwargs)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ha' referenced before assignment

Comment: One workaround I found is to manipulate the input data by adding one sample for non-binary with value 0. The bar_plot function will then work, but of course indicate "0" for non-binary. What I would like is to have no label there at all.

Comment: Seaborn's lead programmer already issued this bug in matplotlib's [github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/20058), just two days ago.  Meanwhile, you can still use the old way: looping through the bars and manually adding a text on top of each.