# Problem in showing the Data Labels in the Bar Chart of catplot

Tags: python, seaborn, catplot

My code is like the below:

```
import seaborn as sns
from itertools import product

titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

sex_order = titanic['sex'].unique().tolist() 
hue_order = titanic['survived'].unique().tolist()
bar_order = product(sex_order, hue_order)

catp = sns.catplot(data=titanic, kind='count', 
                   x='sex', hue='survived',
                   order = sex_order, 
                   hue_order = hue_order )


spots = zip(catp.ax.patches, bar_order)
for spot in spots:
    total = len(titanic[(titanic['sex']==spot[1][0]) & 
        (titanic['survived']==spot[1][1])])
    height = spot[0].get_height() 
    catp.ax.text(spot[0].get_x()+0.125, height+3, '{:1.0f}'.format(total))
```

And the output chart is as follows:

[image: catplot]

Now my question is that why the number of count for some of bars are shown wrongly.
For example, for the red arrow and the yellow arrow. Their number are interchanged with each other.

How can I fix this Problem?

Comment: It is looped in the numerical annotations, but isn't the order Male, Male, Female, Female?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: To get the correct order instead of looping through `ax.patches` you can loop through `ax.containers` as there is one container per hue. You can call the new `ax.bar_label(ax.container_i)` which takes care of positioning the correct labels.

Comment: Thanks JohanC. Excuse me, but I don't get the code.
Do mean that my code has to change as follows?
`spots = zip(catp.ax.containers, bar_order)
for spot in spots:
    total = len(titanic[(titanic['sex']==spot[1][0]) & 
        (titanic['survived']==spot[1][1])]) 
    catp.ax.bar_label(ax.container_i, '{:1.0f}'.format(total))`
I get the below error 
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'bar_label'

Comment: Well, it's a **new** function. You need the latest matplotlib (3.4.2).

Comment: See also [Bar labels in matplotlib seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67112449/bar-labels-in-matplotlib-seaborn)