# Plotting seaborn histplot bar_label with condition

Tags: python, matplotlib, formatting, seaborn

I want to plot a [seaborn histogram](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html) with [labels](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar_label.html) to show the values of each bar. I only want to show the non-zero values, but I'm not sure how to do it. My MWE is

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

xlist = 900+200*np.random.randn(50,1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
y = sns.histplot(data=xlist, element="bars", bins=20, stat='count', legend=False)
y.set(xlabel='total time (ms)')
y.bar_label(y.containers[0])
## y.bar_label(y.containers[0][y.containers[0]!=0])
plt.show()
```

The graph looks like

[image]

and I want to remove all the `0` labels.

Comment: possibly related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67112449/bar-labels-in-matplotlib-seaborn

Comment: not really related... I just want to get rid of all the `0` labels

Comment: It means you can iterate over `y.containers` and use `ax.text` to manually label the bars yourself.

Comment: I i wanted to round the bar labels, how would i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

A best version suggested by @BigBen:

```
labels = [str(v) if v else '' for v in y.containers[0].datavalues]
y.bar_label(y.containers[0], labels=labels)
```

Try:

```
labels = []
for p in y.patches:
    h = p.get_height()
    labels.append(str(h) if h else '')

y.bar_label(y.containers[0], labels=labels)
```

[image]